# Codename One Native Call to iOS QR Reader

Tags: ios, codenameone, qr-code

We need to read Inverted QR Codes on both Android and iOS.

On Android we wrote a piece of native code to use QRDroid to do the scanning as it is capable of scanning both regular and inverted codes.

On iOS the standard barcode reader app is also capable of reading both  regular and inverted codes.

Is there a way to to use the native app to do the scanning and then simply grab the output from it to use in our own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sample of native code we wrote implemented ZXing in iOS and the current code for [QR reading is a cn1lib](https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan/) you can easily edit to do anything.

We also created a [cn1lib for scandit](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-codescan-scandit/) which is a proprietary scanner library. You can use those as references.

The state of code scanning on iOS is a bit worse than Android so I'm not sure if you'll find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Shai, we were trying to avoid hacking away at the code scan library but if it has to done it has to be done.

Comment: We went for the cheap workaround. 1. Take a photo, 2. Invert the image colour, 3. Upload to http://api.qrserver.com/v1/read-qr-code/ to decode the qr code.

Comment: That might create a sub-par UX. If you need help getting native integration working we're here.

Comment: There is no native iOS SDK qr scan support?

Comment: There is, the code-scanner SDK as well as a couple of others